# \ifnum for datatool package

Tags: conditionals, datatool

I'm trying to write quotes and depending on "males" selected, it needs to change the output.
Unfortunately, in the example below it gives me **2skip** although it should give me **2males**. What am I doing wrong?

```
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{filecontents*}{excel.csv}
included,givenname,matriculation,gender,grade
Maier,Hans,12345,m,1.0
Huber,Anna,23456,f,2.3
Weisbaeck,Werner,34567,m,5.0
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{CounterO}{excel.csv}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lccc}
\DTLforeach*[\DTLiseq{\gn}{m}]{CounterO}%
    {\gn=gender}
    {%
        \DTLiffirstrow{}{\\}
    } 
\end{tabular}

\newcommand{\CounterA}{\DTLsavelastrowcount{\CounterI{}}}
\CounterA
\ifnum \CounterA > 1
males
\else
    \ifnum \CounterA = 1
    male
    \else
    skip
    \fi
\fi

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test needs to be against `\CounterI`, not `\CounterA`:

```
% ...
\newcommand{\CounterA}{\DTLsavelastrowcount{\CounterI}}
\CounterA
\CounterI\space
\ifnum\CounterI=0
  skip%
\else
  male\ifnum\CounterI>1 s\fi
\fi
```

Comment: It works :) - thank you, but I'm confused that `\CounterA` doesn't give a value anymore. Is the line of putting the value onto `\CounterA` necessary then?

Comment: @ChrisPeh: No, it's not. You can just use `\DTLsavelastrowcount{\CounterI}` directly.